# Time derivative in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any support for time derivatives in TensorFlow ?

Let's say that we have a tensor of `shape=(batch_size, timesteps, feature_size)` and we want to compute the time derivative for each element in the batch (along the second dimension). What is the best way to do this in tensorflow ?

What functions from the api could be reused in order to mimic the behaviour of [Finite Difference schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) for any derivative order and accuracy, also keeping the same number of timesteps in the derivative as in the original tensor (e.g. by using forward/backward schemes at the start/end, but central difference schemes for the rest)

Thank you for any advice.